# Flask multiple threading use db connection

Tags: flask, rabbitmq, flask-sqlalchemy, pika

I am trying to use db connection in flask in  separate thread.I tried using flask sqlalchemy but if i try using the app context i can't access the db session in the thread. I have read that we have to use sqlalchemy and its not possible using flask sql alchemy. My main task is to perform db operation using  rabbitmq pika in a separate thread which involves db operation

Comment: show us the code of what's not working

Comment: Can you share some sample code.

Comment: @mmenschig can i ping you personally